# Let $\mathcal{T}$ = {$(-\infty,a)| a\in \mathbb R$} and let $A = (-1,1)$ $B = (-\infty,1]$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}$ = {$(-\infty,a)| a\in \mathbb R$} and let $A = (-1,1)$ $B = (-\infty,1]$.

(i) Compare this topology with the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.

(ii) Find $\operatorname{int}(A), \operatorname{int}(B), \operatorname{cl}(A)$ and  $\operatorname{cl}(B)$.

$A$ and $B$ are in this topology.

Comment: $\mathcal{T}$ isn’t actually a topology on $\Bbb R$, but $\mathcal{T}\cup\{\Bbb R,\varnothing\}$ is and is probably what is intended. Is it a subset of the standard topology? A superset? Neither? That’s what (i) is asking. (ii) is really very straightforward, especially the first two parts. What members of $\mathcal{T}\cup\{\Bbb R,\varnothing\}$ are contained in $A$? In $B$?

Comment: Sorry i am not really good at it but talking about (ii), wouldn't that depend on $a$? Let's say can i take $a = -2$ and say no members are contained in $A$? Hope that is not too dumb to ask @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You have to consider all possible values of $a$. For instance, $(-\infty,2)$ is not contained in $B$, but $(-\infty,-2)$ **is** contained in $B$. As for $A$, it’s true that $(-\infty,-2)\nsubseteq A$, but what about other members of $\mathcal{T}\cup\{\Bbb R,\varnothing\}$?

Comment: So their interiors are themselves?@BrianM.Scott

Comment: Clearly not, since they are not open in this topology: neither of them is in $\mathcal{T}\cup\{\Bbb R,\varnothing\}$. But for each of $A$ and $B$ there is a largest member of $\mathcal{T}\cup\{\Bbb R,\varnothing\}$ contained in that set.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir! @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal{T}$ as you gave it is not a topology yet, you have to add $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$ to it to get a topology.

All sets in $\mathcal{T}$ are also open in the usual topology so it's a coarser topology than the usual one. Strictly so, because $(0,1)$ is a standard open set but not in $\mathcal{T}$.

If $A= (-1,1)$ then $A$ does not contain any member of $\mathcal{T}$ so $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$.

If $B = (-\infty, 1]$, the largest open set contained in $B$ is clearly $(-\infty,1)$ which is thus the interior of $B$.

Closed sets in $\mathcal{T}$ are $\emptyset$, $\Bbb R$ or of the form $([a,+\infty)$ (the complements of the sets in $\mathcal{T}$).

So the smallest closed set containing all of $A$ is $[-1. +\infty)$, which is thus $\operatorname{cl}(A)$.

The *only* closed set (and so certainly the smallest) containing $B$ is $\Bbb R$, which thus equals $\operatorname{cl}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you kindly!